# Laravel Lazy Loading Reference $this->property in Load() custom constrain

Tags: orm, eloquent, laravel-5, constraints

I have a relation on a model which I need to lazy load on my controller but I need to do a query constraint using a property from the original model.
So I have something like:

```
$Users = User::all();
$Users->load(['disputes' => function($query){
 $query->where('property', $this->property );
}]);
```

But it returns Undefined property $account_number_tu.
How can I make sure $this is referencing each $User in $Users when doing a load()?
I tried doing this constraint within the model but

```
$this->property;
```

returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, `load()` initializes an instance of the `Builder` on the `User` model and then passing the params you passed to `load` to the `with` method on builder.  With this you can do everything in the `load` method that you can with the `with` method.

To answer your question you can do:

```
$Users = User::all();
$Users->load(['disputes' => function($query) {
    return $query->select('disputes.*')
        ->leftJoin('disputes', 'disputes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->whereRaw('users.property = disputes.property');
}]);
```

Which would be the same as:

```
$Users = User::with(['disputes' => function($query) {
    return $query->select('disputes.*')
        ->leftJoin('disputes', 'disputes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->whereRaw('users.property = disputes.property');
}]);
```

Comment: So disputes is another table, for example if user has a property called phone I can do whereRaw('disputes.phone' = users.phone'); ?

Comment: Correct. Under the condition that `users` and `disputes` are the name of the tables (if not then swap those with the actual table names with prefixes).

Comment: The names of the tables I am actually trying to query are 'disputes' and 'score_aware_disputes_accounts'.  Those are the names as shown in MySQL, but I keep getting error Column not found.  I am doing my query like whereRaw('disputes.account_id = score_aware_disputes_accounts.id');

Comment: It specifies it cannot find the column 'score_aware_disputes_accounts.id'.  Its like it does not try to look in the specified table.

Comment: What is the `disputes` relationship on `User` defined as?  ie: `$this->hasMany(Dispute::class);` What are the key column names for that relationship?

Comment: The relationship is declared as hasMany('App\Dispute', 'account_number', 'account_number_tu');  So account number is the key in Disputes table, and account_number_tu is the key of the score_aware_installment_accounts table.

Comment: There it is.  Those should be reversed.  The hasMany relationship is `hasMany($related, $foreignKey, $localKey)` And I made an error, that 2nd query isn't being run till after the first so technically that table isn't there.  Up edited the original response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127740/discussion-between-jsrosas-and-eric-tucker).